# How to get other celDiv Data from first celDiv radio button?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a table

```
<table>
<tr><td><input radio name="R1" onClick=getOtherColumnData()>first</td><td>TR1-TD2</td><td>TR1-TD3</td><td>TR1-TD4</td></tr>
<tr><td><input radio name="R1" onClick=getOtherColumnData()>Second</td><td>TR2-TD2</td><td>TR2-TD3</td><td>TR2-TD4</td></tr>
<tr><td><input radio name="R1" onClick=getOtherColumnData()>first</td><td>TR3-TD2</td><td>TR3-TD3</td><td>TR3-TD4</td></tr>
</table>
```

Now, when i click on radio button, how to get the other columns data?
I am trying to use

`$(td)('nth-child(3) div').text();`

but it is returning all row's 3rd TD data, but i want just return for that perticular row for which radio button is clicked.

Appreciated your help!

Nilesh

Comment: Can you post your html here ?

Comment: while you are trying to write code in your question, you should select code and take it in code blocks with ctrl+k, this will make your code visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given you're already using jQuery, why not use it to bind the click handlers? Then within the handler `this` will refer to the clicked radio, and `$(this).closest("tr")` will give you the row that it sits in. From there you can use `.find()` or `.children()` to get other cells of that row, if you want to select a specific cell by index or some other selector. Or you can use `$(this).parent()` to get the cell the radio is in and `$(this).parent().siblings()` to get the other cells in the row.

```
$('input[name="R1"]').click(function() {
    var $tr = $(this).closest("tr"),
        cell3content = $tr.children().eq(2).text();  // get content of third cell
    // or
    var $allOtherCellsInRow = $(this).parent().siblings();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you should pass `this` parameter to your function, than you can get other columns data,

```
<table>
<tr><td><input type="radio" name="R1" onClick=getOtherColumnData(this)>first</td><td>TR1-TD2</td><td>TR1-TD3</td><td>TR1-TD4</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="radio" name="R1" onClick=getOtherColumnData(this)>Second</td><td>TR2-TD2</td><td>TR2-TD3</td><td>TR2-TD4</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="radio" name="R1" onClick=getOtherColumnData(this)>first</td><td>TR3-TD2</td><td>TR3-TD3</td><td>TR3-TD4</td></tr>
</table>

<script>
function getOtherColumnData(e) {
   $(e).parent().siblings().each(function() {
        alert($(this).html());
    });        
}
</script>​
```

[you can see here a live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kwnDS/2/)